# How to create new angular app without downloading node_modules files

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-material, angular-cli

I'm new in angular and every time I want to create new angular application it downloads approximately 316MB files from internet.

I was wondering if there is any way to skip downloading node_modules folder and just download other angular files neccessary to run my app and then copy&paste my (existing) node_modules folder to root folder of my app.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Copy `package.json`, `package-lock.json` and `node_modules`. `node_modules` usually doesn't contain any project specific files or configurations.

Comment: you can use  `ng new project-name --skip-install` to create a project without installing node_modules and later copy them locally.

Comment: skip install what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can run the command `ng new <YourProjectName> --skip-install`, It will create a package without node_modules folder.

[image]

Comment: Thanks . --si is not recognized but --skip-install works as expected

Comment: I was using very old version of angular clue 1.4.3. You are right, this alias has become obsolete now. See my question https://stackoverflow.com/q/75352888/6527049

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. Copy `package.json`, `package-lock.json` and `node_modules`. `node_modules` usually doesn't contain any project specific files or configurations.