# Error: Unknown argument: si using Angular CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am running the following command (alias si) and getting the below error.

```
ng new MyProject --si
```

Error:

> Error: Unknown argument: si

Although I am able to create the project using `ng new MyProject --skip-install`

Running the command `ng version` gives the below details.

Angular CLI: 15.1.3

Node: 18.13.0

Package Manager: npm 8.19.3

OS: win32 x64

I have followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OUcn0SvHUws&list=PL6n9fhu94yhWUcq5Pc16uf8YKXoZ87Vh_&index=5) youtube tutorial, and the tutor used the same command successfully at time 3:20. My assumption here is that the alias `si` is obsolete now. Because I don't see an alias in help also.

[image]

Comment: Afaik aliases use single dash.

Comment: @Eldar I have tried single dash as well.

Answer (score 0):

yes, the author of this video uses very old Angular(1.4)
You can see it here ([Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MKApWSDJeiw&list=PL6n9fhu94yhWUcq5Pc16uf8YKXoZ87Vh_&index=2)) 3:06

Comment: So is this alias obsolete?

Comment: Yes, use --skip-install. Why do you watch this video? If you have to support a legacy application, ok. But if you use the video for learning,  you should avoid it, because this Angular version is too old, and the common with modern Angular is only a name